What are the main views in mereology?
I am currently aware of 2 views: mereological nihilism and mereological universalism. Are there any other views?

These two examples only concern classifications based on the composition question, which is one of several in mereology, see SEP. And aside from universalism and nihilism, there are various versions of restrictivism and deflationism, see IEP, Material Composition.

There is мereological essentialism, which states that the only objects that exist are quantities of matter, which are things defined by their parts. The object persists if matter is removed or the form changes, but the object ceases to exist if any matter is destroyed.
